# Why I can't connect dockerized gitlab runner to a dockerized gitlab ci?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

On a dockerized gitlab-runner bash:

```
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
http://localhost:4311
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
xxxxxxxxxxxx
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[runner]: dockerizedrunner
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
powershell
Whether to run untagged builds [true/false]:
[false]: true
Whether to lock Runner to current project [true/false]:
[false]: false
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=xxxxxx status=couldn't execute POST against http://localhost:4364/api/v4/runners: Post http://localhost:4364/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4311: getsockopt: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

I tried this with 3 forwarded ports (22,80,443 forwarded to 4311,4312,4313). How should I set it up?

Comment: How do you run `gitlab` and `gitlab-runnet`. Could you show us some `docker-compose` files, or commands for running this containers.

Comment: actually I do docker run gitlab/gitlab-ce and docker run gitlab/gitlab-runner. Then in kitematic I forward ports for gitlab-ce (22,80,443)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type `http://localhost:4311` in `gitlab-ci` actually `localhost` refers to host **inside** container. This is not `localhost` of your local PC. Therefore `gitlab-ci` could not connect to `gitlab`.

I recommend you to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)  to orchestrate several containers.